# Initialise a Svelte app based on a promise

Tags: vue.js, authorization, keycloak, svelte, sveltekit

I have previously developed several Vue apps using [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) for authentication and authorization. For Vue apps, Keycloak provides [a solution](https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue#_create_a_vue_app) to ensure that unauthenticated users cannot load the Vue app by only initializing the app when the user is authenticated.

```js
keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then((auth) => {
  if (!auth) {
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    Vue.$log.info("Authenticated");

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      render: h => h(App, { props: { keycloak: keycloak } })
    })
  }
...
```

Now, I am working on a Svelte project and I would like to apply the same approach. Is there a way to initialize a Svelte app based on a promise, similar to how it is done in Vue with Keycloak?

I have already tried searching for solutions, but I have not been able to find anything that specifically addresses this problem for Svelte.

To me, the biggest advantage is that you're always 100% sure the user is authenticated and you always have access to the JWT token to send to the backend if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Svelte on its own, you can use the [Client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api)

```
import App from "./App.svelte"

keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then((auth) => {
  if (!auth) {
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    new App({
      target: document.getElementById('#app'),
      props: { keycloak: keycloak } })
    })
  }
```

In a SvelteKit app, you can use the **src/routes/+layout.js** to add global behaviors:

```
// layout.js
import { browser } from "$app/environment";

/**
 * @type {import('./$types').LayoutLoad}
 */
export const load = async () => {
  let keycloakPromise;
  if (browser) {
    keycloakPromise = keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then((auth) => {
      if (auth) {
        return keycloak;
      }
    });
  }
  return {
    keycloak: keycloakPromise,
  };
};
```

```html
<!-- layout.svelte -->
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  /** @type {import('./$types').LayoutData} */
  export let data;

  onMount(() => {
    if (!data.keycloak) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
</script>

{#if data.keycloak}
  <slot />
{/if}
```

When `data.keycloak` is undefined, the authentication failed.
This allows rendering the contents conditionally.

(the code example assumes keycloak is a client-side authentication)

Comment: Is there an argument / a reason for having part of the logic inside `layout.js` and not do everything inside `onMount` in `layout.svelte`?

Comment: Wonderful Bob! This solved my question!

Comment: @Corrl In this example the onMount has the same behavior, but the benefit of layout.js is that it runs before navigation and load functions of nested pages can use the auth result with parent() https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-parent-data